# Programmatically exec into docker container

Tags: bash, shell, docker, go, exec

I would like to write a program that allows the user to choose a running docker container which they can be given an interactive shell to. The flow of the program I would like to have is roughly the following:

1. user runs program from bash - `./my_program`
2. user is given an
   interactive cli they can use to choose which docker container to
   `exec` into
3. when user chooses container, something like `docker exec -it <CONTAINER_ID> bash` is run from `my_program`, `my_program` exits, and the user is transferred into a shell session of the docker container as if they had manually run `docker exec -it <CONTAINER_ID> bash`

I'm trying this from golang with the following code:

```
rv, err := exec.Command("docker", "exec", "-it", containerId, "bash").Output()
log.Infof("RV: %v", rv)
if err != nil {
    log.Errorf("Error exec-ing into container: %s", err)
}
```

and see the following output:

```
RV: []
Error exec-ing into container: exit status 1
```

I'm trying with `err := exec.Command("docker", "exec", "-it", containerId, "bash").Run()` as well and see the same error.

How might I go about creating a program like this or debugging what's currently happening?

Comment: You need to tie the stdout/stderr of your go exe to the exec.Command, so you will have proper console control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are launching your docker exec in interactive mode (`-i`) and with a tty (`-t`) the `exec.Command` needs to be provided a means for the user to send input/receive output from the tty.

To tie the cmd's stdin/stdout directly to your `go` process:

```
cmd := exec.Command("docker", "exec", "-it", containerId, "bash")

cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout

err := cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

// reached once user types `exit` from the bash shell
fmt.Println("Docker: bash console ended successfully")
```